# Laravel eloquent query to return sum of month orders

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have so far came up with this query:

```
Order::select(DB::raw('sum(price) as sums'), 
              DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%e') as day")                                             
             )
             ->where('seller_id', Auth::user()->id)
             ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()
             ->subMonth(),Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->subMonth()])
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
             ->groupBy('day')
             ->get();
```

This returns an array like this:

```
[{"sums":145867,"day":"3"},{"sums":19567,"day":"28"}]
```

This is almost what I need. I would now like to include even the name of the month in these results, like this:

```
[{"June" : {{"sums":145867,"day":"3"},{"sums":19567,"day":"28"}}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, add month to your select and use collection method mapToGroups

If you don't want to see month number in result array - format result array in callback

```
...
DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%c') as month")  
...
->get()
->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [Carbon\Carbon::create()->month($item['month'])->format('M') => $item];
});
```

Also you can use DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%b') for month name from MySQL and don't use Carbon in callback, but, in my opinion, it's not good for possible localization. But this way more performance effective

Comment: Using this solution, I get this:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'orders.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select sum(price) as sums, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%e') as day, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%c') as month from `orders` where `seller_id` = 11 and `created_at` between 2021-06-01 00:00:00 and 2021-07-01 23:59:59 and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null group by `day` order by `created_at` asc)

Comment: oh, strict mode - add month to groupBy: ->groupBy('day', 'month')

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding month to groupBy solved it. Disabling strict mode in database.php in config also worked :)